# How to have a function recieve pointers as arguments?

Tags: c, function, pointers, declaration, implicit-conversion

I am currently trying to complete a Homework Assignment for one of my college courses, and am stuck.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void add(int *a[], const int *b[], const int *c[], int size); /* Function Prototype */

int main() {
  int a[5];
  const int b[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
  const int c[] = {1,1,1,1,1};
  add(a,b,c,5);

  for(int i=0; i < 5; i++) {
    printf("%d\t", a[i]);
  }
  return 0;
}

void add(int *a[], const int *b[], const int *c[], int size) {
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
  a[i]=b[i]+c[i];
 }
}
```

I am trying to have the function add receive its arguments as pointers instead of as int arrays. I have consulted the textbook, and some of my peers but I am still generally confused. If anyone could please shine some light on why my above implementation does not work?

These are the errors I get:

```
main.c: In function 'main':
main.c:9:7: warning: passing argument 1 of 'add' from incompatible pointer 
type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   add(a,b,c,5);
   ^
main.c:3:6: note: expected 'int **' but argument is of type 'int *'
 void add(int *a[], const int *b[], const int *c[], int size); /* Function 
Prototype */
  ^~~
main.c:9:9: warning: passing argument 2 of 'add' from incompatible pointer 
type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   add(a,b,c,5);
     ^
main.c:3:6: note: expected 'const int **' but argument is of type 'const int *'
 void add(int *a[], const int *b[], const int *c[], int size); /* Function 
Prototype */
  ^~~
main.c:9:11: warning: passing argument 3 of 'add' from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   add(a,b,c,5);
       ^
main.c:3:6: note: expected 'const int **' but argument is of type 'const int *'
 void add(int *a[], const int *b[], const int *c[], int size); /* Function 
Prototype */
  ^~~
main.c: In function 'add':
main.c:19:14: error: invalid operands to binary + (have 'const int *' and 'const int *')
     a[i]=b[i]+c[i];
      ~~~~^~~~~

exit status 1
```

Comment: `int *a[]` is an *array of pointers to `int`*.

Comment: `int *a[]` indicates an array of pointers to `int`, not a single pointer. Either `int *a` or `int a[]`.

Comment: This was so simple, I must read up on pointers again obviously. Is there any feasible reason to want an array of pointers to int?

Comment: Arrays of pointers to structures are common, but I've never had a use for an array of pointers to int.

Comment: An array of pointers to `char` are common too, such as the program argument `char *argv[]`.

Comment: *As a function parameter*, `int *a[]` is a pointer to pointer to int, equivalent to `int **`.  It is **not** an array of pointers to int, though it might well point to the first element of such an array.  This differs from when the same form is used to declare a block- or file-scope variable.

Comment: Make sure you really understand what @JohnBollinger says here, because this is the hub of the issue.  It's a common source of confusion for C beginners, and if you don't understand it, you'll wade into more trouble later.  The inventors of C used a clever trick, and it pays to thoroughly understand that trick.

Comment: You should have tried searching "c array parameter". I found this: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_passing_arrays_to_functions.htm

Comment: @RobertLD - arrays of pointers to scalar types often show up when you want to create a "jagged" array, where each "row" may be a different length, or when you don't have enough memory to allocate a large 2D array in a single chunk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the C Standard (6.7.6.3 Function declarators (including prototypes))

> 7 **A declaration of a parameter as ‘‘array of type’’ shall be
>   adjusted to ‘‘qualified pointer to type’’**, where the type qualifiers
>   (if any) are those specified within the [ and ] of the array type
>   derivation. If the keyword static also appears within the [ and ] of
>   the array type derivation, then for each call to the function, the
>   value of the corresponding actual argument shall provide access to the
>   first element of an array with at least as many elements as specified
>   by the size expression.

So these function declarations declare the same one function

```
void add(int a[5], const int b[5], const int c[5], int size); 
void add(int a[5], const int b[10], const int c[15], int size); 
void add(int a[], const int b[], const int c[], int size);
```

and are equivalent to the declaration

```
void add(int *a, const int *b, const int *c, int size);
```

Take into account that according to the same C standard the function `main` without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```

Also it is a bad idea to use magic "raw" numbers as 5.

The program can look like

```
#include <stdio.h>

void add( int *a, const int *b, const int *c, size_t size); /* Function Prototype */

#define N   5

int main( void ) 
{
    int a[N];
    const int b[N] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    const int c[N] = { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 };

    add( a, b, c, N );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ ) 
    {
        printf( "%d\t", a[i] );
    }

    return 0;
}

void add( int *a, const int *b, const int *c, size_t size ) 
{
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < size; i++ ) 
    {
        a[i] = b[i] + c[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that the array "lengths" in the function parameters are ignored. They only matter when there are 2 or more dimensions, for all but the first dimension, so that the compiler can compute the indexing. Otherwise, there is no length constraint in C (with some exceptions when initialising).

Answer (score 3):

**Short version:**

Change your function declaration and definition from

```
void add(int *a[], const int *b[], const int *c[], int size)
```

to either

```
void add(int *a, const int *b, const int *c, int size)
```

or

```
void add( int a[], const int b[], const int c[], int size )
```

**Slightly longer version**

Under most circumstances, when the compiler sees an *expression* of type "N-element array of `T`", it will replace it with an expression of type "pointer to `T`" and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element in the array<sup>1</sup>.

Thus, in the function *call*

```
add(a,b,c,5);
```

each of the expressions `a`, `b`, and `c` is converted from "5-element array of `int`" to "pointer to `int`".  So your function prototype needs to be either

```
void add( int *, const int *, const int *, int )
```

or

```
void add( int [], const int [], const int [], int )
```

In the context of a *function parameter declaration*, `T a[N]` and `T a[]` are interpreted as `T *a` - they all declare the parameter as a pointer to `T`, not an array of `T`.

The array subscript operator can be used on pointer expressions as well as array expressions, so you don't have to change the body of your `add` function - in fact, the subscript operator is *defined* in terms of pointer arithmetic.  The expression `a[i]` is evaluated as `*(a + i)` - given a starting address `a`, offset `i` *elements* (not bytes!) from that address and dereference the result.

---

1. The exception to this rule is when the array expression is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators.

Answer (score 1):

In `void add(int *a[], const int *b[], const int *c[], int size)`, an argument like `int *a[]` denotes an array of pointers to ints, not an array of ints.
Simply declare/define your `add`-function as `void add(int a[], const int b[], const int c[], int size) { ...` and it should work.